# What do factory markings on the inside of DUPLO pieces mean?

Tags: piece-information, duplo

In addition to LEGO and DUPLO names embossed inside the pieces of early DUPLO figures, there are a variety of number formats (one to three digits, some hyphenated) and in the case of 1977, the year.

Is there an explanation for what these numbers mean - and can they then be associated with a particular set and/or year?

Comment: Similar question: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1399/what-does-imprinted-information-inside-bricks-mean?rq=1

Answer (score -2):

The markings are the Batch number and element id.

Comment: You should add more details to your answer like describing the format and your references

Comment: Woo, War Kings! (I blame and thank autocorrect)

Comment: I think they are Mould Ids rather than "batch" numbers specifically...