# LEGO minifig authenticity

Tags: minifigures, collectable-minifigures

I bought 3 mini figures from Amazon because I wanted specific mini figures and did not want to spend $30 plus doing so with bag ordering and opening. I got the figures and they look authentic.

The LEGO logos are on the nub of the torso and the little bridge part of the legs. However, not on the bottom of the legs.  I have 20 something minifigures that I opened from bags, they all have the logo on the bottom of the legs.  So I'm a little confused by it?

Comment: Can you share a picture of the minifig? Or even better - comparing it with a confirmed LEGO minifig to show the perceived differences?

Answer (score 2):

Some of the minifig parts that are officially made in China (often including the Collectable Minifigures) don't have the copyright/logo stamp on the inside toe - I noted that in a comment to my answer on [What does the imprinted information inside bricks mean?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/1400/56)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it all depends on the age of the piece. Throughout lego history they have changed through various different manufacturing methods. one of the biggest being the change from yellow to skin colour and some smaller ones being the ventilation on top of the head. It would also provide a lot of help with an addition of a picture.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bootleg version of lego from china. If the minifigure print wears off in a few days, its  probably bootleg. It is probably made by lele, sheng yuan, or sluban.